# presto: error while query from information_schema.columns

Tags: presto

When run sql `select * from hive.information_schema.columns;` in presto client. I get the error infomation:

> Query 20170208_085534_00061_ny9tu failed: outputFormat should not be accessed from a null StorageFormat

However, It succeed when select from other table in information_schema like `select * from hive.information_schema.tables;`

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug caused by a table that has metadata we aren't expecting.

I scan all tables in hive and find some tables' InputFormat/OutputFormat is null. It will get the same error information if I `DESCRIBE TABLENAME` for those table with null InputFormat/OutputFormat in presto.

[reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/XwNuIzVRnSA)